# Range of an argument of a function in VBA

Tags: excel, function, arguments, vba

Is there a common method of getting range of a given argument of a function or at least getting an argument of a function as an Object, for example:

```
Function func(x1 As VarType_1, ..., xn As VarType_n)
    .......
End Function


Sub sub_1()
    '1)
    Dim x1_domain
    x1_domain = func.x1.VarTypeDomain
    'or at least:
    '2)
    Dim arg1 As Object
    Set arg1 = func.x1
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean "range" or do you mean "multiple arguments"? A "range" is a group of one or more cells.  If you mean "multiple arguments" then what you want is a function that takes a **parameter array** (`ParamArray`").  ...as for objects - sure.  Functions can take any data type as a parameter.

Comment: oh... and are you asking about what you can pass to the function as an argument, or what you can return from the array?  (or both)

Comment: I mean "multiple arguments" - array of possible values of a function parameter.

Comment: I'm asking about how to assign an array with values that I can pass to the function to a variable.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262341(v=vs.60).aspx
You can create your own type which can store multiple arguments and use that type as the outcome of your function.